# Rails POST params not accessed in controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write an application that will have to interact with POST but I'm having issues accessing the parameters.  This is not meant to be useful right now but I'm just trying to flash the result of the form.  According to google dev tools, the POST parameter is set to 1.

Here's my routes.rb file

```
 devise_scope :user do
  put 'users/toggle_activation' => 'users/sessions#toggle_activation' 
  get 'users/sign_out' => 'users/sessions#destroy'
  post 'pages/home' => 'users/sessions#activities'
end
```

This is the controller in question

```
  def activities
    params.permit(:tennis)
    current_user.save
    flash[:notice] =  params[:tennis]
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

This is the form code

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box :tennis %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using "form_for", then the check_box name will result as "user[tennis]", not just "tennis". View source in your browser and you should see this.

Do something like the following in your controller method (although I'm not sure how it will be called with "form_for :user" because your "activities" route isn't in your routes.rb in the code above):

```
user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:tennis)
flash[:notice] = user_params[:tennis]
```

Comment: If I don't have a model to associate with the form, should I use something else instead of form_for?

Comment: @user3833362 yup, form_tag http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms

Comment: I edited my controller to use the method above and it worked! Thank you for your time